# Count 2 tables same query - PG 9.3

Tags: postgresql, count, cte

I've got two tables that I need a count on both of them.

```
table1: id
table2: cid (table1.id = table2.cid) -- Join can be done by this.
```

I already got two queries that I'm using, and wanna put them in one single query.

Query related to `table1`:

```
WITH c_status AS (
select 
CASE 
  WHEN regdate = 1 THEN 'yes'
  WHEN regdate = 2 THEN 'no'
  from table1
  end as status_1
)

select status_1, count(*) AS c_status_count from c_status group by status_1
```

OUTPUT:

```
yes 548
no  2269
```

Query related to `table2`:

```
WITH u_status AS (
select 
CASE 
  WHEN regdate = 1 THEN 'yes'
  WHEN regdate = 2 THEN 'no'
  from table2
  end as status_2
)

select status_2, count(*) AS u_status_count from u_status group by status_2
```

OUTPUT:

```
yes 564256
no  31452345234
```

Question:

How can I put those two queries together? I want one single query reporting both counts.

UPDATE: Desired output:

```
u_status yes    548
u_status no     2269
c_status yes    564256
c_status no 31452345234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be achived in the following fashion:

```
WITH 
c AS  -- This part of CTE for counting on table 1
(
    -- This select will just return ONE row
    SELECT
        sum(case when regdate = 1 then 1 end) AS c_status_yes,
        sum(case when regdate = 2 then 1 end) AS c_status_no
    FROM
        table1 
),
u AS   -- And this one for table 2
(
    -- This select will also return just one row
    SELECT
        sum(case when regdate = 1 then 1 end) AS u_status_yes,
        sum(case when regdate = 2 then 1 end) AS u_status_no
    FROM
        table2 
)
-- And you just put everything together
SELECT
    c_status_yes,
    c_status_no,
    u_status_yes,
    u_status_no
FROM
    c, u ;  -- This is a 1x1 CROSS JOIN, don't worry
```

NOTE: the little trick: `sum(case when regdate = 1 then 1 end)` is in fact *counting* how many times the `regdate = 1` condition is met; when `regdate <> 1` the `case` statement returns NULL, effectively not summing 1 in that case.

---

You can also use a `count(*) filter` instead of a `sum(case when ...)`, although I am not sure this could already be done in version 9.3 (I've tested on 9.4):

```
WITH c AS
(
    SELECT
        count(*) filter (where regdate = 1) as c_status_yes, 
        count(*) filter (where regdate = 2) as c_status_no
    FROM
        table1 
)
, u AS
(
    SELECT
        count(*) filter (where regdate = 1) as u_status_yes, 
        count(*) filter (where regdate = 2) as u_status_no
    FROM
        table2 
)
SELECT
    c_status_yes,
    c_status_no,
    u_status_yes,
    u_status_no
FROM
    c, u ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=257c3d9d502dd5daabbc8f5bb856656b)*